# Geoserver FreeMarkerTemplate GetFeatureInfo Image not showing

Tags: html, freemarker, geoserver, getfeatureinfo

I'm trying to use Freemarker template to show the corresponding picture of a building when clicking on it. The getfeatureinfo functionality works as intended but the picture is not showing when implementing freemarker template.

My freemarker template:

```
<ul>
<#list features as feature>
  <li><b>Building, "${feature.BID.value}"</b>: <br/>
  <img src="http://localhost:8115/geoserver/data/www/hus/fotoinv/${feature.FOTO.value}"/>
  </li>
</#list>
</ul>
```

All the pictures are located in the fotoinv folder.

An image src icon shows up but no picture is showing, when inspecting icon the correct number from the FOTO has been added to the src, e.g /fotoinv/60140 but the image still is not showing.

Appreciate any help on this since it's my first time working with Geoserver and FTL's.

Answer (score 0):

An image that is stored in the `www` directory is served at `http://localhost:8080/geoserver/www/` so on my local machine I have a file called `logo.png` in the `data/www` folder to display it in my browser I need to use `http://localhost:8080/geoserver/www/logo.png`.

**Note**: that location will only work for users on you physical machine. If you want remote users to see the pictures then you will need to use `http://machine.domain.com/geoserver/www`

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I have a layer of buildings that each have an feature ID named FOTO, i am trying to pull a specific picture with the same ID as the clicked building from my www directory. This has, as previously mentioned, not worked. I've now even tried your method which just pulls one picture and does not use the ID from a specific building but the result is the same. I've tried testing this in both geoserver layer preview and in my own web application with my openlayers map. My pictures are JPG files and are named e.g. "6435" and not "6435.jpg", with .jpg it hasnt worked either.

Comment: What doesn't work? Is the url generated correctly? Does the template work?

Comment: The actual template seems to work since i've been able to use it for other things, for example making the feature info be in a bullet list. But for some reason the picture won't show, when inspecting the src icon the url seems to be correct so i do not know what might be causing the issue.